# How to set a Steam group to public?

Tags: steam

I'm considering setting my Steam community group to public so that anyone may join, but I can't figure out how or where to change the setting.

[This Steam Support page](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2092-QLZX-8453#privacy) states that I should:

> 1. Login to your Steam Community Profile. Select GROUPS and click the
> 2. Visit admin page link next to the group you wish to edit.
> 3. Select the Settings tab and click the circle next to the Group Status option that you would like for your group.
> 4. Click Save

But after I click the admin page link, I don't see a Settings tab, nor can I find the Group Status option in any of the other settings sections.
What am I missing? Surely I'm overlooking something here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I open steam and go to my group, I click "edit group permissions" under **Admin tools** At the top it says:

> Public - Anyone can join
>
> Invite Only - People can only join by being invited

There you can select a circle.

This should do it. Not that hard?

In your case when you click: "visit admin page" go to edit group permissions on the right.

Comment: Aargh, there it was all along! Thank you. I guess that support page is outdated...